# What is the oldest known Chinese audio recording?

Tags: history, audio

I have tried search engines and Wikipedia articles on the history of audio recording, in English and Chinese, but couldn't come closer to this.

What is the oldest known recording of anyone speaking (Mandarin) Chinese? Is it available online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fred Gaisberg of EMI made the first Chinese audio recordings 1903-03-18/1903-03-27 in Shanghai.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJ0KBEz23j4

https://vimeo.com/100191126

http://www.recordingpioneers.com/docs/GAISBERG_DIARIES_2.pdf

http://adp.library.ucsb.edu/index.php/resources/detail/378

Comment: Edit: Edison seems to have recorded Cantonese in SF China town in 1902: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBOV-HGTPyc